# terraform aurora 5.7 configuration errors

Tags: amazon-rds, terraform

Does anyone able to provision aurora 5.7 with terraform? I am stuck on the following error. any idea why?

```
    * aws_rds_cluster.default: InvalidParameterCombination: 
    The Parameter Group test-aurora-57-cluster-parameter-group with DBParameterGroupFamily 
aurora-mysql5.7 cannot be used for this instance. Please use a Parameter Group with DBParameterGroupFamily oscar5.6
      status code: 400, request id: 09b5d660-1d71-49bf-a5de-a62b87805038
```

Here's the cluster and cluster instance configurations:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instance" {
       #...
        db_parameter_group_name = "${aws_db_parameter_group.aurora_db_57_parameter_group.id}"
}


resource "aws_rds_cluster" "default" {
          #...
          db_cluster_parameter_group_name = "${aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.aurora_57_cluster_parameter_group.id}"
}

resource "aws_db_parameter_group" "aurora_db_57_parameter_group" {
          name        = "test-aurora-db-57-parameter-group"
          family      = "aurora-mysql5.7"
          description = "test-aurora-db-57-parameter-group"
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group" "aurora_57_cluster_parameter_group" {
     name        = "test-aurora-57-cluster-parameter-group"
     family      = "aurora-mysql5.7"
     description = "test-aurora-57-cluster-parameter-group"
}
```

Comment: Is that definitely the code you are using? The error implies that your DB parameter group family is erroneously set as `oscar5.6` and not the `aurora-mysql5.7` family shown in the code block. Alternatively is the error copied across exactly? Also could you expand the `aws_rds_cluster.default` definition as well? Are you setting the engine version in it?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue with aurora-mysql8.0. @OP did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify engine version for the cluster and instance section.

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora" {
  engine = "aurora-mysql"
  ...
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "aurora_instance" {
  engine = "aurora-mysql"
  ...
}
```